# Fine Uploader - S3 Server Setup Not working

Tags: macos, terminal, fine-uploader

I have just purchased a license for fine-uploader and i am wanting to implement the upload to s3 usage.

When i setup following the getting started pages i get to step 3:
http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/03-setting_up_server-s3.html

I successfully run and install `npm install express aws-sdk` in terminal but when i then try the next step to download the server :

```
wget -O server.js https://raw.github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/master/nodejs/s3/s3handler.js
```

i get this response in terminal:

```
xxxx-iMac-2:~ xxxxx$ wget -O server.js https://raw.github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/master/nodejs/s3/s3handler.js
```

-bash: wget: command not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to ensure wget is installed on your system or is available on your path, according to the error message.

You really don't need wget to get that file though, just navigate to https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/nodejs/s3/s3handler.js.

Comment: thanks for this, sorry very new to using terminal to run and install things